# JavaScript Canvas touch future with multiple eventListeners

Tags: javascript, canvas, touch, event-listener

I need to add a touch feature to the canvas app that I'm working on (multiple users white board), and I already read about the event listeners and the `event.preventDefault()`, but I can't understand how can I use two event listeners with 'DOMContentLoaded' and 'touchmove'. At this point I don't know if using multiple event listeners is the solution I need.

This is the code I'm using:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

   var mouse = { 
      click: false,
      move: false,
      pos: {x:0, y:0},
      pos_prev: false
   };

   var canvas  = document.getElementById('drawing');
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var width   = 1280;
   var height  = 960;
   var socket  = io.connect();
   var lineWidth = 1;
   var shadowBlur = 1;
   var shadowColor = "black";
   var strokeStyle = "black";

   canvas.width = width;
   canvas.height = height;

   canvas.onmousedown = function(e){ mouse.click = true; };
   canvas.onmouseup = function(e){ mouse.click = false; };

   canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
      mouse.pos.x = e.clientX / width;
      mouse.pos.y = e.clientY / height;
      mouse.move = true;
   };

    socket.on('draw_line', function (data) {
       var line = data.line;
       context.beginPath();
       context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
       context.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
       context.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
       context.lineJoin="round";
       context.lineCap = "round";
       context.moveTo(line[0].x * width, line[0].y * height);
       context.lineTo(line[1].x * width, line[1].y * height);
       context.stroke();
   });

   function mainLoop() {
      if (mouse.click && mouse.move && mouse.pos_prev) {
         socket.emit('draw_line', { line: [ mouse.pos, mouse.pos_prev ] });
         mouse.move = false;
      }
      mouse.pos_prev = {x: mouse.pos.x, y: mouse.pos.y};
      setTimeout(mainLoop, 50);
   }
   mainLoop();
});
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you encountering some sort of bug?  Right now it appears that your code operates by listening for the mouse being clicked and the mouse being moved.  If the mouse is pressed down, the mouse is being moved and the loop has run at least once (mouse.click && mouse.move && mouse.pos_prev) then it draws a line on the canvas element.